# The lightest possible nodejs build

Tags: node.js, build, compilation, min

I'm trying to run a small nodejs project on a old router (A part of a challenge) but have ran into problems, as it only has about 6MB of usable memory. First off I ran the build through [upx](https://upx.github.io/) that took the build down to around `6mb`. After that I tried using older builds `iojs and v1.01`. They worked fine except that they lacked features required to run the `ws` module (the other part of the challenge). After that I ran `./configure` with the arguments of `--without-dtrace --without-npm --without-etw --without-perfctr --with-icu-source=none` but they still refused to bring down the build size. Is there a way to build nodejs in such a way that it runs the `ws` module and has an output that's under `6MB`

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2948? It seems like 6MB is a pretty tight constraint.

Comment: Yes, I've already looked into it with not look.

Comment: You might be better off looking into using a JS engine that is intended for low memory (e.g. embedded) devices (e.g. [Duktape](http://duktape.org) or [JerryScript](http://jerryscript.net))

Comment: @Whymarrh would any of these allow me to use the websocket module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to memory issue I think this will not work in your case. 
Try this one [espruino](https://www.espruino.com/) . [Here](http://forum.espruino.com/conversations/263595/) You can read more detally

Answer (score 0):

You should try CivetWeb: https://github.com/civetweb/civetweb It include Websocket and support javascript via Duktape.